# Parametrising a 2D curved spring

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, parametric

This question stems from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32313/214170) `tex.stackexchange` answer, relating to the drawing of a coil in tikz.

The commenter parametrises a straight 2D coil by $$x = D_1\cos(t\pi), y = D_2t + D_3\sin(t\pi),$$ with $D_1$ the radius, $2D_2$ the "wavelength" of one loop and $D_3$ a measure of how wide the loops are. This can be seen in the 1st plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n8zwdxiwu2) (`desmos.com` graph).

I was wondering how one would use this parametrisation to draw a curved coil.

Could one simply use the same equations for $(x, y)$ and write them in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, or it is more involved than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in polar coordinates:
$$
\theta=t\pm\frac{w}{R_1}\cos\frac{2\pi R_1 t}d,\\
r=R_1+R_2\sin\frac{2\pi R_1 t}d,\\
$$
where $R_1,R_2$ are two radii of coil torus, $d$ is wavelength and $w$ is coefficient of how “coiled” the coil is drawn. You can try to [play with parameters](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zuory9bfy7).

Comment: That's brill, thanks. Where did you get this expression from?

Comment: It is just your expression. You just forgot to shift r by $R_1$

Comment: I see. Just because yours was in a slightly different form, I wasn't sure if you got it from somewhere else